# How to remove "$" sign from input value

Tags: jquery

I have this code which I got after searching. The only thing I want to do is remove the `$` sign from the `input` value but when I try to remove it, I am not getting any output.

```
$(function() {
    $defaultValue = $('.total').val();
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(event) {
        var total = 0;
        $("input:checked").each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).parent().find('.inv-total').text().substring(1));
        });

        if (total == 0) {
            $('.total').val($defaultValue);
        } else {
            $('.total').val('$' + total);
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="invoice">
    <input type="checkbox" checked='checked' value="1" />
        <span class="inv-total">$100</span>
</div>

<input type="text" class="total" value="$90" />
```

Comment: Trying to remove "$" from the input. Only want number like 100 and 90.

Comment: `'$100'.replace(/\D/g, '')` will return `100`.

Comment: do you mean from `.total`?

Comment: @skobaljic Sure, blindly copy paste something he has no idea what will do. OP: This will replace any (`/g`) character that isn't a digit (`\D`) with nothing `''`.

Comment: It will do the job for him. And what it does is: remove all non-digits from string.

Comment: can you give a case on how it should work...

Comment: In simple, i want to remove all $ sign from input and from js(which relates to input)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `replace`, ex:

```
$defaultValue = $('.total').val().replace('$','');
```

and last `if else` condition remove **$** to concate with total,

```
$('.total').val(total);
```

View this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/reyagidako/1/edit)

create a function like this:

```
function __esc(el){
return el.replace('$','');
}
```

and filter all elements you want to escape $

Comment: i want to remove all $ sign from input and from js(which relates to input)

Answer (score 0):

code Modified:

Js:

```
$(function() {
    $defaultValue = $('.total').val();
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(event) {
        var total = 0;
        $("input:checked").each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).parent().find('.inv-total').text().substring(1));
        });

        if (total === 0) {
            $('.total').val($defaultValue);
        } else {
            $('.total').val(total);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="invoice">
    <input type="checkbox" checked='checked' value="1" />
        <span class="inv-total">$100</span>
</div>

<input type="text" class="total" value="90" />
```

Comment: I already tried above code. Code doesn't work If 100 is used on place of $100